# UINavigationBar disappears when performing segue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I encountered a problem in my app.

I have to have a `UINavigationBar` in all my pages, and so I created a `UINavigationController` 'embed in' with my first page. So the `UINavigationBar` appears on it, but when I perform a segue from that first page (by instating a new view controller and presenting it) the navigation bar doesn't appear on the second view controller.

Comment: Please check it and give me response 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689261/modal-segue-navigation-bar-dissapears

Comment: please provide your navigation code

Comment: How you present new View controller by modally or by using push?

Comment: set the 'second view controller' as a root controller of UINavigation controller. And change the segue destination to the NaviationController.

Answer (score 0):

Check your segue is presenting or pushing a second page.
Check out segue properties, If it's presenting by selection of 'Modal' on segue property of attribute inspector. On presenting view controller you won't get your Navigation bar.
You will get Navigation bar when you push a segue.

And If you want presenting animation on push using segue, You can go for custom segue.
Here is the link.
http://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/