# How to embed a UINavigationController in prepareForSegue?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

Currently I have a `VC1` of type `UITableViewController` that is embedded in `UINavigationController`. When the user selects a cell, it performs a `push` segue to `VC2` also of type `UITableViewController`. That is fine because the navigation bar is still present.

However in `VC1`, there is a `UIBarButtonItem` in the navigation bar, that upon tapped, also segues to `VC2` and performs different things, but it uses all the same menu layout.

Using the `UIBarButtonItem` to segue to `VC2`, I like to perform a `modal` segue to distinguish between the two actions.

I know that `modal` segues encompasses the whole screen, and any top bars will be removed.

I followed this question: [Modal segue, navigation bar dissapears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689261/modal-segue-navigation-bar-dissapears)

One of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37209971/2373410) provided shows how to embed a `UINavigationController` in `prepareForSegue`, so I followed it and implemented:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "AddSegue"
    {
        let navigationController: UINavigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController

        var addVC: VC2 = VC2()

        addVC = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as! VC2

    }
}
```

However, I get the error:

> Could not cast value of type 'VC2' to
>   'UINavigationController'

How can I properly embed a `UINavigationController` in `prepareForSegue` because I need to pass data between different view controllers.

Here's my storyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segue you're intersecting is to your `VC2`, not a navigation controller. You're going to need to update the `"AddSegue"` segue to point to a navigation controller, then link your `VC2` as the root view controller of the navigation controller.

If you post your storyboard, I can give you more details on how to do this.

EDIT: Here's how you should set up your storyboard. It might get a bit weird, since VC2 has two parent navigation controllers, but it should be fine.

[image]

Comment: how does this help me perform 2 different types of segue while maintaining the navigation bar?

Comment: You're not maintaining the original navigation bar. When you present VC2 modally, you're essentially creating another navigation stack (and without embedding it in a navigation controller, the stack will always have 1 view controller and no bar). The second navigation controller I added should instead be presented modally, thus giving you the navigation bar for VC2.

Comment: is there no way to do it programmatically without using storyboard to embed another navigation controller?

Comment: Not in the way you were trying. You can't change the destination view controller during a segue, and you have your segue hooked up directly to VC2.